# How to impose a global constraint on cost function of a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, constraint

I have a training set of time series samples. Each sample is composed of a noise process (input) and the corresponding trajectory (output) which is the solution of the stochastic differential equation for the noise. Ideally a convenient neural network (like RNN) can learn the relation between the noise and the trajectory.

But in this case, there is an additional constraint. The average of trajectories (outputs) over noise processes satisfies a function (let's call it, 'global function'. Note that, statistically speaking, the global function is present in each sample, but due to the presence of the noise, the neural network has a hard time finding it.

The question is how can I incorporate the global function directly into the learning process so that the network satisfies this function?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the description of the constraint. What's the average taken over? What's the function that must be satisfied? What does it mean that 'the function is present in each sample'?

Comment: @user20160 I've updated the post to provide more context. The average is taken over the noise processes. By 'the function is present in each sample' I mean, one can find the function by averaging the trajectories over noise. So, the function is already inside the data.

Comment: If you know the function then what’s the point of the neural net?

Comment: @Dave To avoid confusion, let's call the function, 'global function'. The point is, in general, solving stochastic differential equations is computationally expensive. So, I want to build a neural network to learn the solution. I need the solution (trajectories). The global function is a constraint: it is the average of solutions over noise.

Comment: What I'm hearing is that you need the function to include it in your neural net, but you want to find the function using the neural net instead of solving the SDE, which is a catch 22. Where am I going awry with this?

Comment: @Dave I think you are confusing the prediction of neural net and the global function, that the outputs should satisfy. I found a related post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746005/how-to-restrict-the-sum-of-predicted-outputs-in-a-neural-network-regression-usin